# Shortcut Can't Start Activity

Tags: android, shortcut

- I created some shortcut of my activities by code, most of them can't
  open its related activity. I found that it only work if I added
  filter CREATE_SHORTCUT to activity. Why?

  ```
     <activity
         android:name=".ui.Main"
         android:launchMode="singleTop"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
  ```

  (test in Go Launcher & MIUI 2.3.7)
- I got logs below, should I add MAIN filter?

  09-27 13:34:44.075: E/Launcher(7893): Launcher does not have the
  permission to launch Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
  flg=0x10000000 cmp=/.ui.Activity2    bnds=[349,76][469,211] }. Make
  sure to create a MAIN intent-filter    for the corresponding activity
  or use the exported attribute for this    activity.

Comment: Did you try to add `android:exported="true"` to your activity? (Although it should by default be true because of the intent filter).

Comment: I'll have a try, never used it before. thx.

Comment: @Matt Handy, Thank you. I need to add exported="true" to all activities.Have no idea what caused.

Comment: Don't know if this is what you want. Then all of your activities can be accessed by other apps.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want. You should post it as answer, so I can accept it and vote it.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you could add

```
android:exported="true"
```

to your activity.

Although this should be the default value if I read the android documentation right:

> **android:exported**
>
> Whether or not the activity can be launched by
>   components of other applications — "true" if it can be, and "false" if
>   not. If "false", the activity can be launched only by components of
>   the same application or applications with the same user ID. The
>   default value depends on whether the activity contains intent filters.
>   The absence of any filters means that the activity can be invoked only
>   by specifying its exact class name. This implies that the activity is
>   intended only for application-internal use (since others would not
>   know the class name). So in this case, the default value is "false".
>   On the other hand, **the presence of at least one filter implies that
>   the activity is intended for external use, so the default value is
>   "true"**.

Maybe someone else can clarify this.

Comment: It is clear in the documentation -- if you add a <intent-filter> with action MAIN, then it becomes implicitly exported; or you can directly set exported to true. Both will make the activity exported and launchable by the launcher.